# How to get the text of a selected option in an unordered list jquery

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul class="ui-body-e" id="clientsList"   data-filter="true"  data-inset="true" data-role="listview" >

            <li id="entryTemplate" class="entry" style="display:none">
                <a href="#cliMaLi" data-transition="slide">
                <span class="fnameLabel">Label</span> <span class="snameLabel">Label</span></a>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

```
 // Generate client list
function refreshCliLi () {
$('#menu ul li:gt(0)').remove();
JLEGALDB.transaction (
function(transaction){
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT id, fname, sname FROM clients;', undefined,       function(transaction, result){
        for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
             var row = result.rows.item(i);
             var newEntryRow = $('#entryTemplate').clone();
             newEntryRow.removeAttr('style');
             newEntryRow.data('entryId', row.id);
             newEntryRow.appendTo('#menu ul');
             newEntryRow.find('.snameLabel').text(row.sname);
             newEntryRow.find('.fnameLabel').text(row.fname);
             }
    }, errorHandler);
});
```

}

The items in the clients list are generated from the database.
When a clients name is selected in the clients list how can I get the text of that selection???

Comment: Selected how? You have no form elements.

Comment: You should post a fiddle from www.jsfiddle.net demonstrating basic functionality, it makes it easier for people to help you..